# Rspec test if a new action is removed in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rubygems, activeadmin, rspec-rails

How to test if new action is removed from ActiveAdmin by Rspec test? If it is passed in the url like /properties/new it will throw an error. I've removed the action.

```
describe "GET new" do
    it "should raise an error" do
      get :new
    end
  end
```

It returns

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/properties"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [be_routable rspec matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs/be-routable-matcher) to verify the route

```
  describe "GET new" do
    it "not to be routable" do
      expect(get: :new).not_to be_routable
    end
  end
```